# Problem with github pages and web deployment

Tags: github, github-pages

I did git bash on the project files also I copied the commands GitHub gave me into the git terminal and I went to GitHub pages and selected the branch main:

[image: selecting the branch main]

and have been waiting for 15 minutes to see the link to my project

[image: the GitHub code of my project]

but when I clicked the link to see my project on GitHub pages it gave me just the repo name of my project

[image: the GitHub page of my project]

How can I view my project?

Answer (score 0):

Your site is actually already available at https://abdelrhmanboy.github.io/test-compas/Kompas.html.